# libraryDependencies with multiple lines

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to understand the `build.sbt` file. I'd like to organize my `build.sbt` file a little bit better and add a dependency per line.

I read the documentation and it says that I need to use the keyword `Seq` and have a format similar to this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  groupID % artifactID % revision,
  groupID % otherID % otherRevision
)
```

and I thought I understood the documentation, but apparently not because when I try to add multiple dependencies this way:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.typelevel",
    "cats-core" % "2.0.0",
    "org.scala-lang.modules",
    "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.1.2"
)
```

I get the following error:

```
build.sbt:26: error: No Append.Values[Seq[sbt.librarymanagement.ModuleID], Seq[Object]] found, so Seq[Object] cannot be appended to Seq[sbt.librarymanagement.ModuleID]
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
                    ^
[error] Type error in expression
```

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and after endless Googling I couldn't find an example of a `build.sbt` with multiple lines in it.

Comment: How is this: `ID % artifactID % revision,` equivalent to `org.typelevel",
    "cats-core" % "2.0.0",` ? You have a comma _(`,`)_ where a double percent isgn _(`%%`)_ is expected.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error and I was constructing my `buildDependencies` the wrong way. I changed it to:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "2.0.0",
    "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.1.2"
)
```

and it worked.

I guess I didn't fully understand the difference between `%%` and `%`

Comment: `foo %% bar` is the same as `foo % bar_scalaVersion` - So, because **Scala** doesn't guarantee binary compatibility across minor versions, libraries have to be published for each minor scala version you want to support, and thus you have to import the correct library artifact on your projects. Because specifying the correct scala version si tedious and error prone, SBT introduced `%%`